# Google analytics stopped working after adding another account

Tags: google-analytics

I am using google analytics on my mobile app. All was working fine since 3 months until few minutes ago when i added another project ( a website ) . Now my mobile app doesn't longer respond ( It's okay for the website). Even worse, i lost all my analytics data since 3 months just like if it never exists. It's a nightmare. All i did is adding a new account in google analytics. I can't believe all my analytics data are lost.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: "Now my mobile app doesn't longer respond" - Is your app broken or GA on app? How did you add account? Are you admin of your GA? More details are needed.

Comment: My app still running without problem. The issue is related to GA. I simply added the new account from GA console then initialized GA in my web app. Yes i am the admin.